# wrong event listener execution

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var total = 0;

        document.getElementById("pic1").addEventListener("click",
                choix(1), null);
        document.getElementById("pic2").addEventListener("click",
                choix(2), null);
        document.getElementById("pic3").addEventListener("click",
                choix(3), null);
        document.getElementById("pic4").addEventListener("click",
                choix(4), null);

        function choix(num) {
            switch (num) {
            case 1:
                total = total + sessionStorage.getItem("prix1");
                break;
            case 2:
                total = total + sessionStorage.getItem("prix2");
                break;
            case 3:
                total = total + sessionStorage.getItem("prix3");
                break;
            case 4:
                total = total + sessionStorage.getItem("prix4");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            alert(total);
        }


    </script>
```

Assuming that I have created 4 items (using the localStorage.setItem method),the problem is that I got the 4 alerts displayed even without clicking on any div!

What's the problem? Thank you!

Comment: You're not passing a reference to the `choix` function, you're _executing_ it.

Comment: True, but I am didn't click on any div! how is it possible to execute the "choix" function without the click event?

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

You are executing `choix` and passing the return value to the `addEventListener` method instead of passing a reference to the function itself.

```
document.getElementById("pic1").addEventListener("click",
                choix(1), null);
```

### Example

What you are doing is exactly the same of:

```js
function sayHello(lang){
  if(lang == "en")
    return "Hello";
  else if(lang == "it")
    return "Ciao";
  else if(lang == "es")
    return "Hola";
  else
    return "";
}


console.log( sayHello("en") ); // Prints "Hello"
```

Here we are passing the return value of `sayHello` to `console.log`

### Solution

You should call it in this way

```
document.getElementById("pic1").addEventListener("click", choix);
```

And then find what was the button inside the callback

```js
var total = 0;


function choix(num) {

  var btnID = this.getAttribute('id'); // Get Button ID
  var index = btnID.substr(3); // Cut out "pic"
  
  total = total + sessionStorage.getItem("prix"+index);

  alert(total);
}
```